# Defining and accessing costum properties of an HTML-element

Tags: javascript, css

In a web project, technical business-related values have to be attached to specific elements. Based on those values, decisions are to be made on the client side. One big advantage of this approach, were it possible, is that CSSs in my case are automatically generated from other formats (provided by the management).

I am trying to add my own properties to some CSS classes. I have a css class like:

```
.className{
SomeProp: ThisIsTheValue;
}
```

In Javascript, I need to access this value. I tried things like:

```
myVar.SomeProp
myVar["SomeProp"]
```

All returned null. Is there a way I can just read this value? Is that possible to add my own CSS properties?

Comment: `SomeProp` is not a valid `css` property. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which property you want to access

Comment: I am assigning a custom property to the class! Is that not allowed?

Comment: No, that is not allowed.  Why do you assign the property at `css` file? What is expected result?

Comment: I edited my question above

Comment: The edit does not change the fact that `SomeProp` is not a valid `css` property. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AHH I'm just trying to understand your question - are you trying to make your own CSS properties?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have some good reasons for this, but I am realyzing after this discussion that this is not doable with CSS.

Comment: What are the reasons for using the approach at `css` at Question? Are you trying to store arbitrary data at or associated with the element?

Comment: Those are just organizational reasons. The people who would edit such information usually work on CSS, so this would have been the most convenient way for everybody.

Comment: The value can be stored at `css` text and parsed at `javascript`, though not as currently set at Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this through CSS. The browser will only read the CSS properies that it knows and ignore the rest. You can't read them from JavaScript in any practical way. 
And you shouldn't, because CSS if for styling, not for business logic.

You can however use custom HTML attributes. Using [data*-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-dataset) you can store extra information in an HTML element and read it from JavaScript to use it in any way you like. Mozilla has some [good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on the subject.

Comment: I am investigating exactly this solution. It is not that elegant in my case because the front end will now contain too much information.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to do it in CSS, this means that the element also has that specific class set. So you could check for the existance of the class using [element.classList.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Then you just need to know which attributes belong to that class. Since CSS doesn't work, you might choose to hardcode them somewhere, or pass them as a JavaScript object or JSON snippet to your page somehow. Still, unless you have a very specific use case, it's a cumbersome and unorthodox way to achieve the same result as data attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `getComputedStyle()` method in standard JavaScript:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7a2v1e38/)

```
var element = document.getElementById('name'),
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
```

You can use the `top` variable however you please, such as in the example it outputs in an alert.

Comment: `.getComputedStyle()` will not help OP. OP is setting the actual property `SomeProp` at `css` file, which is not a valid `css` property.

Comment: @guest271314 from how OP's original question was worded it sounded like he wanted to read the value of a CSS property via Javascript. After his edit I now see what he's trying to achieve. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`SomeProp` is not a valid `css` property. Use a different approach to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

---

The value can be stored at `css` as `JSON`, within `css` comment. Parse the `.textContent` of `style` element to retrieve value as `javascript` object.

```css
/*{"className":{"SomeProp": "ThisIsTheValue"}}*/
```

```html
<script>
var styles = document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode; 
var obj = JSON.parse(
             styles.textContent
             .match(/(\/\*{.*})(?=\*\/)/)[0]
             .replace(/[/*]/g, "")
             .trim()
          );
  console.log(obj["className"]["SomeProp"])
</script>
```

---